# Data from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 and I need get into it data from Oracle. I go true manual: https://www.sqlshack.com/link-sql-server-oracle-database/
and I stack with files: `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora`

I read and saw youtube manuals how to make values into `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` but it does not work.

Files `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` I try created new but nothing.

Also I try make SSIS in Visual Studio 2010 but I need get Oracle Client in to it but I do not know which one is acceptable for Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks for update manuals..

Comment: Can you connect to both databases individually? if your Oracle instance is already up and running then you shouldn't need to touch the tnsname file

Comment: You can create SSIS package where source will be oracle and destination will be SQL. In destination server you have to make an entry in tnsnames.ora.

Comment: I can not see tables even if i tick : Include Synonyms..

Comment: For Oracle source I need Client in Visual Basic 2010 is well but i do not know which one.. all of them is for VB2013+

Comment: "not work" and "but nothing" aren't Oracle error messages...

Comment: ORA12560 + ORA12541

Comment: MS
 SQL SERVE2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data from Oracle in to MS SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44841316/data-from-oracle-in-to-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is a tool called [Oracle Data Integrator](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/overview/index.html).

There's also an official documentation (link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIKM/ms_sqlserver.htm#ODIKM963)), that describes how to tackle this case in particular.

Another option is to just dump the data into a flat file (csv etc.) and then import it into Oracle using various tools/procedures etc.

There's also [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm), which describes such a migration.

Another option is to use SQL Developer (free, supplied by Oracle); check this thread [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/o57sql-100253.html).

May be [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/sql-server-to-oracle) is also an option worth checking.

Cheers